# Endless loop when pulling XML data into new custom post type [PHP]

Tags: php, xml, custom-post-type

As you can see below I have created some code that will get the data out of my XML file and then add this data into posts in my custom post type 'jobs'

```
$wpbb_xml_content = file_get_contents('http://xxxxxx.co.uk/export/peach-upload.xml' );

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $wpbb_xml_content );

foreach ($xml->ExportTable as $ExportTable) {


$title = wp_strip_all_tags( (string) $ExportTable->Job_x0020_Title );
$content = (string) $ExportTable->Job_x0020_Descritpion;

$wpbb_job_post_args = array(
'post_type' => 'jobs',
'post_title' => $title,
'post_content' => $content,
'post_status' => 'publish'
);


$wpbb_job_post_id = wp_insert_post( $wpbb_job_post_args );


}
```

The issue I'm having with this code is that it's getting the data out of the XML and creating posts with each table entry of the XML feed, but its endlessly looping so i should only have ~26 posts but it continuously creates the 26 posts over and over, so all I want it to do is stop once it gets to the end of the XML feed, I'm wondering if I have tackled this incorrectly with my current code.

Example of how the XML feed looks:

```
<Export>

  <ExportTable>
    <Job_x0020_Title>title 1</Job_x0020_Title>
    <Job_x0020_Descritpion>desc1</Job_x0020_Descritpion>
  </ExportTable>

  <ExportTable>
    <Job_x0020_Title>Title 2</Job_x0020_Title>
    <Job_x0020_Descritpion>desc2</Job_x0020_Descritpion>
  </ExportTable>

</Export>
```

Comment: The iteration terminates after processing all elements, so the loop might come from the logic invoking the iteration.